# How can I Wrap <li> html elements with limited CSS availability?

Tags: html, css

As a disclaimer...this is definitely a "worst case scenario" type question.
  (I only wish it were hypothetical)
I am currently working on formatting lists within a chatbox sidebar (w: 500px, h: 410px) the problem of course would seem to be that the list elements aren't wrapping, an issue typically solved with a bit of CSS, but therein lies the rub...a CSS style sheet is appended to each sidebar after the fact through some proprietary script to which I have no access, the only styles that can be reliably passed, are usually in a  `<td>` and some other tag elements where it isn't defined by a pre-set style.

my code currently looks something like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 480px;">

      <ul>
        <li>Some long string of garbage that goes on and on and on.......</li>
        <li>Some long string of garbage that goes on and on and on.......</li>
        <li>Some long string of garbage that goes on and on and on.......</li>
      </ul>

    </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

`<style> XXX; </style>` is out
`<div style="xxx;">` is no go
`<ul style="xxx;">` can set some properties but not ones common to defining the width of the list or line-break / white-space properties.
`<li style="xxx;">` works similarly to `<ul style="xxx;">`

That said, is there any good work around, other than trying to get in contact with the tool dev team to try and get these items to wrap as they should (other than half a billion `<br>` tags) with such limited CSS?

Comment: `<ul style="xxx;"> can set some properties but not ones common to defining the width of the list or line-break / white-space properties.` why only some?

Comment: Can you write your own CSS rules and use `!important` to override the css coming from the 3rd party?

Comment: The big question to your answer is can you insert your own CSS rules? If you can, simply ensure your rules have a higher specificity. I would also like to point out that `<li>` wrap just fine on their own, so the chatbox or something else is changing this behavior. What level of control do you have over the markup? How are you able to apply styles via the `styles` attribute to some elements and not other? What prevents you from using the `<style>`?

Comment: @dippas they seem to be using some form of BB code as they do have some custom tags, so they may have either limited the properties which they recognize, or it may already be otherwise overwritten when it is displayed/saved

@Teddy I will give `!important` a try and see how it goes...I have a sneaking suspicion it won't work.

Comment: @hungerstar `<style>` elements are filtered out upon saving changes, the same is true of `<div>` tags containing the `style` property. I know all too well that the behavior IS being changed after the fact (this is not typically an issue if you're not stuck with badly developed tools ), but my level of access to change any of these default styles in non-existent unfortunately...

Comment: @Teddy `!important` is no go :(

Answer (score 0):

Is javascript an option? You could use it to apply styles. You could do something like

```
document.getElementById(id).style.property=new_style
```

This would leave the css file untouched.

Comment: perhaps not directly (any JS has to be added in terms of their proprietary system..no `<script>` tags), but I may be able to work something on that angle as there is a spot to create custom JS functions (to some extent..)  maybe something along the lines of:

`function overwriteCSS(id, property, style) {...}` but with this tool even that is likely a long shot